# Error when I installed scikit-learn in conda

Tags: python, scikit-learn

When I tried to install scikit-learn in conda, I received below error

```
$ conda install scikit-learn 
Fetching package metadata ...........
Solving package specifications: .

Package plan for installation in environment     
/Users/xlnwel/anaconda/envs/ai:

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    scikit-learn: 0.19.0-np113py36_0
    scipy:        0.19.1-np113py36_0

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

ERROR conda.core.link:_execute_actions(335): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::scipy-0.19.1-np113py36_0'.
FileExistsError(17, 'File exists')
Attempting to roll back.



FileExistsError(17, 'File exists')
```

I thought it might because the scipy already exists, so I tried to delete scipy, still received an error:

```
$ conda remove scipy
Fetching package metadata ...........
Solving package specifications: .


PackageNotFoundError: Package not found: Conda could not find '
```

What can I do now?
I'm using Mac.

Comment: what does `conda list` print out in console?

Comment: It contains `scipy 0.19.1 <pip>` but no scikit-learn

Comment: the answer below might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If the dependencies are already satisfied try to install `scikit-learn` package ignoring the `scipy` package:

  ```
  conda install --no-deps scikit-learn
  ```

Answer (score 0):

All these tricks didn't work in my ubuntu machine.

Eventually, need to specify numpy and scipy version.  You can get the version by

```
conda list > /tmp/conda_tmp1
pip install -U scikit-learn
conda list > /tmp/conda_tmp2
diff /tmp/conda_tmp1 /tmp/conda_tmp2
```

then check the output